# Slice For Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got an easy one, I want to split out a var of names into a slice High charts
trying with data.map using index and item, directly the data

https://playcode.io/636616

As you can see here, the slice got all the names for all the slices but there might be one name for each slice so can you help me please

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var resp = [];
    var resp2 = [];
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data=>{
      data.forEach(res=>{
        // console.log(res.name);
        resp.push(res.name)
        resp2.push(Math.random());
        console.log(resp,resp2);
    })
    console.log('-->',resp)
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Nacimientos Datos por Comunidades Autónomas, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: resp,
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: resp2
            
        }]
    });

      
        });
    </script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set names for points, not for series:

```
resp2.push([res.name, Math.random()]);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5patLum/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data